# How can I change the descriptor on Stripe Connect Payouts

Tags: stripe-payments

I run a coach matching service where I match coaches to clients for monthly coaching.

Currently, I'm using Stripe subscriptions with Stripe Connected accounts to payout the coaches each month (I take a fee through Stripe)

The issue I'm having is that receipts the coaches receive aren't very useful as they only shows the Stripe payout id (po_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX) and not which clients they're being paid for.

I would like to send them an email each month instead that linkes the payout id to who've they've coached. How can I do this with Stripe's API?

Answer (score 0):

The body of your question seems different from the title.

You can read about Payout descriptors with Connect [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payout-statement-descriptors).

For the summary of payments (and associated services) in a given payout, take a look at the example [here](https://stripe.com/docs/expand/use-cases#charges-in-payout) showing how you can get this list of payments when using automatic payouts.